# Datagridview isn't always filled

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently working on a project wheere, for each category and subcategory of my products, I need to do some inspections. Here's how my winforms works:

1. I click on the first combobox which indicates categories

[image: First step]

2. I select a subcategory on the second combobox

[image: Second step]

3. The datagridview is generated, and generates with itself some data measure samples. Depending on the inspection criteria, I get 1,3,5 or 7 measures. I get the maximum number of measures n, then generate columns n times, and do not give the right to n-k columns for each k<n.[image: Step 3]

The issue I'm facing is that, it only fills the first time, and not the other times. Can anyone please help me out with it?

Here's the code I'm using :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";
                row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";
                row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";

                row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
                row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
                row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;

            }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
                {
                    string connectionstr2 = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security = True";
                    SqlConnection cn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionstr2);
                    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                    System.Data.DataTable dt2 = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    string a = comboBox1.Text;
                    cmd2.CommandText = $"SELECT section FROM Type where typee = '{a}' ";
                    da2.SelectCommand = cmd2;
                    da2.SelectCommand.Connection = cn2;
                    da2.Fill(dt2);
                    comboBox2.Enabled = true;
                    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "section";
                    comboBox2.ValueMember = "section";
                    comboBox2.DataSource = dt2;
                    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;


            }
        }
```

Above is the code to generate the combobox, and below is the code to generate the datagridview, which is bound to a database I already created :

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            string w = comboBox2.Text;
            int t = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";
                row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";
                row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = "";

                row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
                row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
                row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = false;

            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
                {
                
                nombredemesures = new int[] { };

                    dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = this.dataSet1.Tolerance;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => col.Visible = false);
                    richTextBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["ItemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["ItemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;
                    dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Visible = true;


                    dataGridView2.Columns[$"toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
                    dataGridView2.Columns[$"toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
                    dataGridView2.Columns[$"toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
                int deb1 = 0;
                int fin1 = 0;
                int deb2 = 0;
                int fin2 = 0;
                int deb3 = 0;
                int fin3 = 0;
                var result = from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows where row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() is "" select row;

                List<DataGridViewRow> lignes = result.ToList();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "1")
                    {
                        if (deb1 == 0)
                        {
                            deb1 = row.Index;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "2")
                    {
                        if (deb2 == 0)
                        {
                            deb2 = row.Index;
                            fin1 = row.Index - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "3")
                    {
                        if (deb3 == 0)
                        {
                            fin2 = row.Index - 1;
                            deb3 = row.Index;
                        }
                    }

                }

                fin3 = lignes.Count;
                //lot1
                var cell1 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[deb1].Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                cell1.RowSpan = fin1 - deb1 + 1;
                cell1.Value = "1";
                cell1.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;


                var cell2 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[deb2].Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                cell2.RowSpan = fin2 - deb2 + 1;
                cell2.Value = "2";
                cell2.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

                var cell3 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[deb3].Cells["lotDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                cell3.RowSpan = fin3 - deb3 + 1;
                cell3.Value = "3";
                cell3.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                    {


                        CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView2.DataSource];
                        int i = row.Index;
                        currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();

                        if ((row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "")&&(row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is ""))
                        {


                            row.Visible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            t++;
                            string[] splitter = new string[3];
                            try
                            {
                                string a = dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString();

                                if (a.Contains('-'))
                                {
                                    splitter = a.Split('-');
                                    row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = splitter[0];
                                    row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = splitter[1];
                                    row.Cells["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = splitter[2];


                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value = a;

                                }



                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                            }


                        }








                        currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();


                    }


                }
           if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text)))
            {
                List<int> intValues = new List<int>();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {

                    if (!(row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is ""))
                    {
                        var a = row.Cells[$"donnees{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value;
                        if (!(a is DBNull))
                        {
                            intValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
                        }


                    }
                }
                int max = 0;
                foreach (int value in intValues)
                {
                    if (value > max)
                        max = value;
                }
                for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add($"Test{i}", $"Donnée de mesure {i}");
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                    {
                        row.Cells[$"Test{i}"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                        row.Cells[$"Test{i}"].ReadOnly = true;


                    }


                }


                int k = 0;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {

                    if (!(row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is ""))
                    {


                        try
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= intValues[k]; j++)
                            {
                                row.Cells[$"Test{j}"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                                row.Cells[$"Test{j}"].ReadOnly = false;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        }

                        k++;
                    }
                }

                dataGridView2.Columns.Add("a0", "Jugement OK");
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add("a1", "Jugement Non OK");
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add("a2", "Double contrôle valeur");
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add("a3", "Double contrôle OK/NOK");


                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a4", "N°Etiquette");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a5", "Etiquette Emballage C");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a6", "Etiquette Emballage nonC");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a7", "Contrôle visuel C");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a8", "Contrôle visuel non C");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a9", "N° Rapport SIIC");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a10", "Etat de de distribution");
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("a11", "OK/NOK");


            }

                for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                }
                
                
                foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    if(row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "")
                    {
                        var cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)row.Cells["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
                        string a = row.Cells["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString();
                        cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
                        cell.Value = "";

                        cell.Value = a;
                        cell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    }
                }



            dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceMinDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceNomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView2.Columns["toleranceMaxDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ReadOnly = true;




        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not filling after the first time? Do you mean that the rows in the `DataGridView` doesn't generate or do you mean that the measured numerals aren't added to the `DataGridViewCells` when the `ComboBox` selected index is changed after the first time?

Comment: I just mean that the background color that I set to gray doesn't change after the 2nd time. It's gray the first time that I change the selected index item, but it remains white after.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your `DataGridView` by calling the `yourDataGridView.refresh()` method after adding all cells and setting the colors of them?

Comment: I have but it doesn't do anything. The cells aren't colored the second time